# Android Issue: Can't add more then 11 views on a ScrollView

Tags: android, view, scrollview, max

This is my first question on stackOverflow, so lets go:

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/set_reader_tv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Reader Settings:"
android:typeface="serif"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left"
>
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget42"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2px"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#88ffffff"
android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
/>
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/set_auto_mark_cb"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Auto mark as read"
>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/set_auto_mark_cb12"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Auto mark as read"
>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/set_unread_cb"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Show unread only"
>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/set_skip_cb"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Mark as read on skip"
>
</CheckBox>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/set_click_tv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="On feed content click, do:"
android:typeface="serif"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_marginTop="10px"
>
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget41"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2px"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#88ffffff"
android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
/>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/set_action_spin"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5px"
android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
android:layout_marginRight="5px"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>
</Spinner>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/set_account_tv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Change reader account:"
android:typeface="serif"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left"
android:layout_marginTop="10px"
>
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget42"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2px"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#88ffffff"
android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/set_account_btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Change">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But if i add one more view (CheckBox, TextView, LinearLayout) on this layout (not in RunTime, in CodeTime, i havent tried to do it in RunTime), when i open this (setContentView(sv)), it says:

> Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@462fa1b0

I can change any view, but i cant add new one.

This is my inflate code:

```
LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)inf.inflate(R.layout.layout_settings, null);
//More code here
```

So, there's any maximum of view that a ScrollView can host?

Thx Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem in having more widgets/components inside your `LinearLayout`.  As far as I know, the only limitation of `ScrollView` is that it should only have one child.  Why are you inflating the layout? You can just use `setContentView(R.layout.layout_settings)`. I tried your xml file and I can add more views without any problem.

Comment: I don't know why so...I inflate to add some Listeners...but thx anyway, i'll do all my layout with coding...

Comment: Listener for what? You can add listeners without having to inflate, I think.